# Taking two inputs, remove newline separated repeats, and return output in bash or java

Tags: java, bash

I'm attempting to take the contents of one file and the output of ls, remove all repeats (without keeping any of them) and put it back into another file, minus the output of "ls". For example, if file "file.txt" contains:

```
hello
world
test
hi
mom
```

And "ls" returns:

```
index
test
worm
folder
```

I want the output to contain:

```
hello
world
hi
mom
```

Omitting test since it was in the output of ls. A major issue is that you can expect the output of ls and the file.txt to be very large, as in...millions of lines in the output of ls, and possibly even millions of lines in the file.

I will have that many lines because I am attempting to find every URL/URI on the internet, which is....large :P

And before I go into a conversation about diskspace, I did the math, and counted up about 600 GB worth of diskspace (since it's just text), however I may be wrong/off by a couple terabytes.

I have several 100 GB of RAM, however, I still want to save as much RAM as possible.

And it's going to be crowdsourced so lets not even GO into bandwidth. I have a couple GB/s of that anyway.

If that doesn't satisfy you, consider it a theoretical situation, in which I still need to save the most hard drive space at a time (meaning as few temp files at a time as possible) and the most RAM at a time, meaning loading as little of a file at a time as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're using GNU tools, then simply:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -printf '%P\n' | sort > listing.txt
sort file.txt > sortedfile.txt
comm -23 sortedfile.txt listing.txt
```

This creates tempory files of size equal to your input, but GNU sort is clever enough not to use too much RAM.

The runtime is `O(n log n)`

Comment: So I forgot to mention that the first line of file.txt needs to remain the first line...oh well. I improvised:

ls | sort > ls.txt;
head -n 1 file.txt > temp.txt;
tail -n +2 file.txt | sort > file.temp;
cat temp.txt;
comm -23 file.temp ls.txt;
rm file.temp ls.txt temp.txt;

If you can think of a better way to do it, feel free to tell me!

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I would advise to build two `List<String>` each filled line by line and apply `removeAll()` to the `List` originating from the file using the `List` originating from `ls` as parameter so only the lines which are not present in the file are kept.

Comment: You may need to explain a little more...code examples?

Comment: `List<String> fileList = ...;
List<String> lsList = ...;
List<String> onlyFileList = fileList.removeAll(lsList);`

Answer (score 0):

how about this way?

```
diff <(ls |sort) <(sort file.txt) |awk -F "> " '/>/{print $2}'
```